# Honda 2016 2.0 litre engine - oil life indicator

Tags: honda, civic, oil-life-indicator

I have a 2016 Honda Civic, 2.0 litre engine.   Since last oil change, I drove 1,600 k.   The oil life indicator has dropped to 30% after I drove 1,600 k.  I had it looked at and the oil was changed and I was advised car not burning oil and dip stick test revealed good oil level, actual oil did not drop.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 0):

The oil life indicator is a measurement of how the oil is performing, not the quantity of the oil in the engine. An oil life indicator takes into account many different factors such as how the vehicle was driven since the last oil change was indicated. [This page states:](https://www.curryhondany.com/servicedept.cfm/page/honda-maintenance-minder-faqs-570/)

> The system counts down oil life based on engine operating conditions (both normal and severe).  The on-board computer continuously monitors engine operating conditions such as speed, engine temperature, ambient temperature, time, and vehicle use to determine when an oil change and regular maintenance is necessary.

In another paragraph, the page goes on to say the following about how many miles you can expect to drive between oil changes:

> The beauty of the Honda Maintenance Minder system is that it automatically adjusts the maintenance intervals based on engine operating characteristics, your driving habits, and the climate that you have operated your vehicle in.  For instance, mild highway driving in a warm climate will maximize the interval between required maintenance.  Depending on the vehicle, this could be as high as 12,000 miles.  On the other hand, short-trip driving in a cold climate may limit the maintenance interval to 3,000 miles or less.  In general, most people who combine city and highway driving find that the Honda Maintenance Minder will indicate maintenance needs about every 6,000 miles.  Most people maintain constant driving habits; this means that mileage between maintenance will be consistent.

There are a plethora of reasons the indicator could have dropped so quickly. One of the chief questions I'd ask, *Are you sure the oil life indicator was reset at the last oil change?* If you are completely sure it was, then it most likely goes back to your driving style and/or how the car has been used. 1,600k (whether miles or kilometers) is not a long distance for oil use, but the engine computer has decided for whatever the reason, the oil has worn out quickly.

Comment: I petition that we make an FAQ question for this.